# Click an SVG to display image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, onclick

I want to turn my SVG(circles) into buttons, when each different circle is clicked I want a different image slider to show up. How would I go about doing this? here is my code..

```
<div id="sidle">
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/SOKER.jpg" alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/VORTER.jpg"alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/MAFYA.jpg"alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/nick-walker.jpg"alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/SOKER-VORTER-DREAM.jpg"alt>
</div>

<circle class="circles" id="SmallStreet" fill="#B9C3C6" cx="692" cy="344.4" r="12.7"title="Small Street"/>
    <circle class="circles" id="BellLane" fill="#B9C3C6" cx="721.9" cy="311" r="12.7"title="Bell Lane"/>
    <circle class="circles" id="Quay-NelsonStreet" fill="#B9C3C6" cx="652.3" cy="327.7" r="12.7"title="Quay and Nelson Street"/>
```

At the moment im trying to show the image slider on click with a button, but it tells me slider is not defined. Here is that code...

```
<button onclick="slider()"></button>
<div id="sidle">
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/SOKER.jpg" alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/VORTER.jpg"alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/MAFYA.jpg"alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/nick-walker.jpg"alt>
  <img class="image" src="img/nelson-street/SOKER-VORTER-DREAM.jpg"alt>
</div>

$(function slider() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("sidle");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if (obj[i].style.display == "none") {
        obj[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        obj[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, so don't iterate over it. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, that's invalid HTML, and DOM methods aren't going to help. Also, you're wrapping your `slider` function in a jQuery object, which makes it a document.ready function, and can't be called by name. If you're going to use jQuery, use jQuery (i.e., use `$('#slider')`, `.each`, and `toggle()`. Review some jQuery tutorials for more on how to get these things working.

Comment: Thank you, stupid of me to forget the toggle function.

Answer (score 0):

we have two method here:
first:
i have two image with unique class or id and i want to show them on click circles:

```
 <div id="sidle">
  <img class="image" id="img-SmallStreet" src="img/nelson-street/SOKER.jpg" alt>
  <img class="image" id="img-BellLane" src="img/nelson-street/VORTER.jpg"alt>
 </div>
 <circle class="circles" id="SmallStreet" /> 
 <circle class="circles" id="BellLane" />
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#SmallStreet").click(function(){ $("#img-SmallStreet").fadeIn();  });
    $("#BellLane").click(function(){ $("#img-BellLane").fadeIn();  });
 });
 </script>
```

or in a simple and better way:

```
 <div id="sidle">
  <img class="image" id="img-SmallStreet" src="img/nelson-street/SOKER.jpg" alt>
  <img class="image" id="img-BellLane" src="img/nelson-street/VORTER.jpg"alt>
 </div>
 <circle class="circles" id="SmallStreet" /> 
 <circle class="circles" id="BellLane" />
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circles").click(function(){ 
        $id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#sidle #"+id).fadeIn();
    });
 });
 </script>
```

i have many images and want to slide it:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    let index = 0;
    let lenght = $(".img").length;
    $(".circles").click(function(){ 
        $index = $(this).index();
        $("img").hide();
        $("img").eq($index).fadeIn();
        $index +=1;
        if($index >= length) $index = 0;
    });
 });
 </script>
```